# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when using useNavigate and useEffect with axios interceptors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am working on React and trying to include Bearer token for private API call. I wrote a private axios to intercept request and response. Then I call it in API.js to get data from server. However, I get this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

It came from `useNavigate` and `useEffect` in `privateAxios.js`

privateAxios.js

```js
import { axiosPrivate } from "./axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";
// import useRefreshToken from "./useRefreshToken";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const usePrivateAxios = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestInterceptor = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
                const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

                if (!accessToken) {
                    navigate("/admin/login");
                } else {
                    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
                }

                return config;
            },
            (error) => Promise.reject(error),
        );

        const responseInterceptor = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => {
                return response;
            },
            (error) => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            },
        );

        return () => {
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
        };
    }, [navigate]);
    return axiosPrivate;
};

export default usePrivateAxios;
```

documentAPI.js

```js
import privateAxios from "../usePrivateAxios";

export const getAllDocuments = (config) => {
    return privateAxios()
        .get("/documents", config)
        .then((response) => response.data)
        .catch((error) => {
            throw error;
        });
};
```

I want to use `useNavigate` to redirect to login so I use this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usePrivateAxios` is a React hook so it must follow the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). In your code you have imported it as `privateAxios` and call it in a function that is neither a React function component nor custom React hook.

Since you are only injecting request/response interceptors into the `axiosPrivate` axios object, there's no need to use the return value from `usePrivateAxios` to make the GET request. `usePrivateAxios` only needs to be called once in the app to add the interceptors, the `getAllDocuments` function can use the `privateAxios` axios object.

Example:

App.jsx

```
...
import usePrivateAxios from "../usePrivateAxios";
...

const App = () => {
  // Setup global axios request/response interceptors
  usePrivateAxios();

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

documentAPI.js

```js
import { axiosPrivate } from "./axios";

export const getAllDocuments = (config) => {
  return axiosPrivate()
    .get("/documents", config)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
};
```